# Can’t password protect wp-login.php, nothing happened

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx 1.6.2, PHP 5.5.23-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 and fastcgi VPS. I setup my WordPress sites with Easy Engine. I want to enable password protect all my WordPress sites "wp-login.php" as well as "wp-admin" area. To test this process I have added following code to site enabled directory (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`) site file (mysite.com).

```
location ^~ /wp-login.php { 
auth_basic      "Restricted Area:WordPress";         
auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/.htpasswd;  
try_files $uri =404; 
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; 
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;     
}
```

My VPS php-FPM use use `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;` so I used it in above code.

Then I created `.htpasswd` file and uploaded to `/var/www` directory and set the permission to `rw-r-----`.

Then I restarted php and nginx with service php5-fpm reload && service nginx reload command. Now when I try access /wp-login.php nothing changed. It's just like the regular login page and not promote any password popup window. I can't see any error or warning.

Due to the above /wp-login.php file password protection not working, I added password protection to the /wp-admin/ folder, then it working. This is my new nginx site enabled config file.

```
server {


    server_name mysite.com   www.mysite.com;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.access.log rt_cache;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com.error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite.com/htdocs;



    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    include common/w3tc.conf; 

    include common/wpcommon.conf;
    include common/locations.conf;
    include common/pagespeed.conf;

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                 }


location /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php {
    allow all;
}


location /wp-admin {
    location ~ /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php$ {
        # Php handler
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    include fastcgi_params;   
    }

    location ~* /wp-admin/.*\.php$ {
            auth_basic "Restricted Area:WordPress";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd; 

        # Php handler
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    include fastcgi_params;   
    }
}

    }
```

Could someone please tell me how do I fix this issue?

Comment: @AlexeyTen I just added the config file and few additional information.

Comment: Move wp-admin before default PHP location

Comment: @AlexeyTen if I move `location ~* /wp-admin/.*\.php$ {` above the `wp-admin` nothing happens. Still, I can't password protect php files. But it password protect `wp-admin/` directory. Is it another package missing issue or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is /wp-login.php already declared inside wpcommon.conf

So, copy /etc/nginx/common/wpcommon.conf to /var/www/example.com/my-wpcommon.conf

Edit this block

```
location = /wp-login.php {
  limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

into

```
location = /wp-login.php {
  limit_req zone=one burst=1 nodelay;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass php;

  satisfy any;
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  deny all;
  auth_basic "Authorization Required";
  auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd;
}
```

then edit your site nginx configuration at /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com, replace

```
include common/wpcommon.conf;
```

into

```
include /var/www/example.com/my-wpcommon.conf;
```

Restart nginx.

However, please check /etc/nginx/common/wpcommon.conf every time you update your EasyEngine in case of new configuration so your my-wpcommon.conf would still be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fastcgi, you need to include your fastcgi processing in the location block for the PHP file.

```
location ^~ /wp-login\.php$ {
    auth_basic "Restricted Area:WordPress";
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/.htpasswd; 
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    include fastcgi_params;   
}
```

Comment: Now it give me this error. `/$ nginx -t && service nginx restart
nginx: [warn] duplicate value "any" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ee-nginx.conf:35
nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_pass" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sitename.com:34
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Comment: My `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` has `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000`. So can I use `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;`? If I use your code and reboot the VPS, nothing happen. Are there any way to view the logs?

Comment: You can see the log under the file you specified in the nginx config file. It is by default under /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when I visit login.php page. Als can't see any error in log file.